# My program throws me an java.lang.ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException

Tags: java, arrays

I have an error in my code and I can't seem to find a solution, please can someone debug my code?

```
import java.util.* ; 

  public class Calculator {
    public static void main(String[] args) {   

    Scanner s = new Scanner(System.in);
    System.out.print("Enter the first number:");
    String a = s.nextLine(); 
    System.out.print("Enter the second number:");
    String b = s.nextLine();   

    int[] num1 = new int[a.length()];
    int[] num2 = new int[b.length()];

    for (int i=0;i<a.length();i++) {
      num1[i] = (int) a.charAt(i);
      num2[i] = (int) b.charAt(i);
    }

    int[] sum = new int[a.length()];

    for (int i = a.length() - 1; i >= 0; i--){
      if (num1[i] + num2[i] >= 10){
        sum[i] = (num1[i]+num2[i]) - 10;
        **sum[i-1] = 1;**
      } else {
          sum[i] = num1[i] + num2[i];   
      }
    }

    for (int i = 0; i < a.length(); i++) {
      System.out.print(sum[i]+" ");
    }  

  }
}
```

Comment: Assuming `if (num1[i] + num2[i] >= 10)` is evaluated to true when `i` reach the value 0, what does index are you trying to access with `sum[i-1]` ? Is this valid ? You should use `nextInt()` to get an integer. Using `nextLine()`, taking the char and casting to int won't give you the correct value of the integer.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`a.length()` might not equal to `b.length()`

Problematic code

```
int[] num1 = new int[a.length()];
int[] num2 = new int[b.length()];

for (int i=0;i<a.length();i++) {
  num1[i] = (int) a.charAt(i);
  num2[i] = (int) b.charAt(i);
}
```

for example: consider case where `a.length()` = `10` and `b.length()` = `2`

Further problematic code:

```
for (int i = a.length() - 1; i >= 0; i--){
  if (num1[i] + num2[i] >= 10){
    sum[i] = (num1[i]+num2[i]) - 10;
    **sum[i-1] = 1;**
  } else {
      sum[i] = num1[i] + num2[i];   
  }
}
```

Comment: What do you assume I should do to improve my code.

Comment: what are you trying to do with this code ?

Comment: My teacher wants me to create a program that takes 2 numbers that are more than 50 digits and use an array to add the sum together.

Comment: current problem in code is that you are assuming length of both numbers are same and iterating over both of them with only one number's limit in mind

Comment: String array1[] = new String[a.length() + 1];
String array2[] = new String[b.length() + 1];

int int1[] = new int[array1.length];
int int2[] = new int[array2.length];

Answer (score 0):

You can do something like this.

```
public static void main(String[] args){
Scanner s = new Scanner(System.in);
System.out.print("Enter the first number");
String a = s.nextLine(); 
System.out.print("Enter the second number:");
String b = s.nextLine();   
int[] num1 = new int[a.length()];
int[] num2 = new int[b.length()];

for (int i=0;i<a.length();i++) {
  num1[i] = (int) a.charAt(i);

}
for (int i=0;i<b.length();i++)
{
  num2[i] = (int) b.charAt(i);
}
int[] sum;
if(a.length()>b.length())
{
   sum = new int[a.length()];
   for (int i = a.length() - 1; i >= 0; i--)
   {
       if (num1[i] + num2[i] >= 10)
          {
              sum[i] = (num1[i]+num2[i]) - 10;
              /*sum[i-1] = 1;*/
    } 
    else {
       sum[i] = num1[i] + num2[i];   
    }
 }

}
else
{
    sum = new int[b.length()];

    for (int i = a.length() - 1; i >= 0; i--)
    {
       if (num1[i] + num2[i] >= 10)
          {
              sum[i] = (num1[i]+num2[i]) - 10;
              /*sum[i-1] = 1;*/
    } 
    else {
       sum[i] = num1[i] + num2[i];   
    }
 }
}


for (int i = 0; i < a.length(); i++) {
  System.out.print(sum[i]+" ");
}
}
```